# ESP8266 данные нагрузки

Tags: flash, ram

Могу ли я узнать на сколько загружена flash, ram и другие подобные параметры контроллера ?

Comment: Вам лучше знать можете вы или не можете :) [даташит](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/148/DOC001148263.pdf) пробовали смотреть?

Comment: мне нужен вывод данных в сериал порт

Comment: Я вас поздравляю, но это не меняет дела от слова совсем, на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить не зная что у вас за ситуация на микроконтроллере :)

Comment: попытаюсь разъяснить 
 на esp8266 wemos поднят веб сервер.
 но это не так важно, я хотел бы узнать, есть ли библиотека или что-то в стандартных функциях,
 что даст мне возможность вывести нагрузку в виде данных. уверен, всё это гуглится. но я не нашёл

Comment: Не выведете, таких данных там нет. Или считать самостоятельно или никак.